# Make Dbo wtih 1Entity containing the same Entity MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

Im fairly new at programming (6months) and getting my ass kicked by EF, so any pointers in the right direction are welcome! 
The aim of my project/exercise is to make a facebook-type app for dog owners and their dogs.

In particular i'm struggling with making a DBO with Dogs and their DogFriends.
The goal is to enter a Dogname in the Form, get the DogId for that Name and add it to a DBO with Dogs and their DogFriends.

Im not really sure on how to go about that. I'm thinking creating a DBO with just DogId-column and DogFriendId-column (but i could be very wrong, as it appears my understanding of EFCore is still very limited^^)

I hope i included all the necessary code for the issue i'm facing, if not, feel free to ask for more

```
     public class Dog : EntityBase<int>
{        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DogFertility DogFertility { get; set; }
    public DogGender DogGender { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }      
    public DogBreed DogBreed { get; set; }        

    public virtual List<UserDog> UserDogs { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DogFriend> DogFriends{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<Dog> DogFriendList { get; set; }

    public Dog()
    {
        UserDogs = new List<UserDog>();
        DogFriends = new List<DogFriend>();
        DogFriendList = new List<Dog>();
    }             
}



    public class DogFriend : EntityBase<int>
{
    public string DogFriendSearchInput { get; set; }
    public string DogFriendFirstName { get; set; }        
    public Dog Dog { get; set; }    

    public DogFriend()
    {      
         DogFriendFirstName = DogFriendSearchInput;
    }
}
```

I got a ViewModel for adding DogFriends

```
     public class AddDogFriendViewModel
{
    public string DogFriendSearchInput { get; set; }
    public string DogFriendFirstName { get; set; }
    public int DogFriendId { get; set; }
    public DogBreed DogBreed { get; set; }
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }       
    public DogFriend DogFriend { get; set; }
    public Domain.Model.Dog Dog { get; set; }

    public AddDogFriendViewModel()
    {
        DogFriendFirstName = DogFriendSearchInput;
    }
}
```

And a form to add DogFriends

```
     <div>
    <form method="post" asp-controller="DogOwner" asp-action="AddDogFriend" asp-route-returnurl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="margin-left:-15px">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <div>
                           <li>                                    
                                <input asp-for="@Model.DogFriendSearchInput" value="@Model.AddDogFriendViewModel.DogFriendSearchInput" asp-route-dogFriendFirstName="DogFriendSearchInput" style="width:400px" type="text" id="DogFriendSearchInput" onkeyup="SearchDogFriends()" placeholder="Search for DogName or DogOwnerUserName.." />
                            <input hidden asp-for="@Model.DogFriendSearchInput" value="@Model.DogFriendSearchInput" /> 
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a asp-controller="DogOwner" asp-action="AddDogFriend" asp-area="" asp-route-dogId="@Model.Dog.Id" asp-route-dogFriendFirstName="DogFriendSearchInput">Add this Dog to @Model.Dog.FirstName's friendslist</a>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>

        </div><br />
    </form>

</div>
```

This is my current Context

```
    public class DogFaceDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>
{


    public DogFaceDbContext()
    {

    }
    public virtual DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserDog> UserDogs { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<DogFriend> DogFriends { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Dog> DogFriendList { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<UserDog>().HasKey(x => new { x.DogId, x.UserId });           
        builder.Entity<DogFriend>().HasOne(x => x.Dog).WithMany(x => x.DogFriends);
        builder.Entity<Dog>().HasMany(x => x.UserDogs).WithOne(x => x.Dog);
        builder.Entity<Dog>().HasMany(x => x.DogFriends).WithOne(x => x.Dog);

        builder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.UserDogs).WithOne(x => x.User);          


    }
```

The relevant part of the Controller (obviously it isn't correct, but i think i could figure this part out for myself if i had the correct DBO):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AddDogFriend(int dogId)
    {

        var model = new DogViewModel();
        model.Dog = _dogFaceDbContext.Dogs.First(x => x.Id == dogId);            
        model.Dogs = _dogFaceDbContext.Dogs;
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddDogFriend(int dogFriendId, string DogFriendSearchInput, AddDogFriendViewModel model)
    {
        var dogfriend = new DogFriend
        {
            DogFriendSearchInput = model.DogFriendFirstName,                
        };
        await _dogFaceDbContext.DogFriends.AddAsync(dogfriend);
        await _dogFaceDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();



        return RedirectToAction("Index", "DogOwner");
    }
```

Big Thanks for helping out a struggling student!

Comment: Please do not use [tag:model-view-controller] for specifc [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] questions (as stated in the tag).

Comment: my apologies, thanks for the update on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My working solution to the problem:

```
    public class Dog : EntityBase<int>
{        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DogFertility DogFertility { get; set; }
    public DogGender DogGender { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }      
    public DogBreed DogBreed { get; set; }        

    public virtual List<UserDog> UserDogs { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DogFriend> DogFriends{ get; set; }       

    public Dog()
    {
        UserDogs = new List<UserDog>();
        DogFriends = new List<DogFriend>();            
    }             
}

     public class DogFriend : EntityBase<int>
{


    public int DogId { get; set; }                              //for foreign key
    [NotMapped]
    public string DogFriendSearchInput { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string DogFriendFirstName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string DogFriendProfilePic { get; set; }
    public int DogFriendId { get; set; } 
    [NotMapped]
    public DogBreed DogBreed { get; set; }
    public Dog Dog { get; set; }

    public DogFriend()
    {

    }
}

      public class AddDogFriendViewModel
{
    public string DogFriendSearchInput { get; set; }
    public Domain.Model.Dog Dog { get; set; }

    public string DogFriendFirstName { get; set; }
    public int DogFriendId { get; set; }
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }       
    public DogFriend DogFriend { get; set; }              

    public AddDogFriendViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

my form to AddDogFriend

```
    <form method="post" asp-controller="DogOwner" asp-action="AddDogFriend">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
<div>      
    <input asp-for="DogFriendSearchInput"  placeholder="Search for DogName.." /><br />
    <span asp-validation-for="DogFriendSearchInput"></span>
</div>

<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.DogFriendSearchInput" value="@Model.DogFriendSearchInput" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" asp-area="" asp-route-dogId="@Model.Dog.Id" asp-route-dogFriendFirstName="DogFriendSearchInput" />
```

my Context

```
      public DogFaceDbContext()
    {

    }
    public virtual DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserDog> UserDogs { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<DogFriend> DogFriends { get; set; }
```

my Get and Post from Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AddDogFriend(int dogId)
    {

        var model = new DogViewModel();
        model.Dog = _dogFaceDbContext.Dogs.First(x => x.Id == dogId);


        model.Dogs = _dogFaceDbContext.Dogs;
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddDogFriend(int dogId, string DogFriendSearchInput, AddDogFriendViewModel model)
    {
        var dog = _dogFaceDbContext.Dogs.First(x => x.Id == dogId);
        var dogFriendToAdd  = _dogFaceDbContext.Dogs.First(x => x.FirstName == DogFriendSearchInput);

        dog.DogFriends.Add(new DogFriend { DogId = dog.Id, DogFriendId = dogFriendToAdd.Id });

        await _dogFaceDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "DogOwner");
    }
```

For further questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Your model structure is wrong and if you're doing code first, then your database relationships will be wrong. You have a circular reference in your Dog model here:

```
public virtual List<Dog> DogFriendList { get; set; }
```

I think if you get your model structure corrected, you'll be able to understand the task a little better. You didn't display all of your classes so I'm not sure what some of the virtual collections are for, but dog should look similar to this:

```
      public class Dog : EntityBase<int>
      { 
        public int Id {get; set;} (PK)      
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DogFertility DogFertility { get; set; }
        public DogGender DogGender { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DoB { get; set; }      
        public DogBreed DogBreed { get; set; }
        public virtual List<DogFriend> DogFriends{ get; set; }
      }
```

Now dog friends:

```
      public class DogFriend : EntityBase<int>
      {
        public int Id {get; set;} (PK)
        public int DogId {get; set;} (FK)
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
      }
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between dog and dog friends (a dog can have many friends) and maybe a many-to-many depending on the business rules (a dog can have many friends and a dog friend can be friends to many dogs).

Now your view model:

```
       public class AddDogFriendViewModel
       {
          public string DogFriendSearchInput { get; set; }
          public Dog Dog {get;set;}
       }
```

I'll skip your html page for now and go to the controller. Your get will be something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddDogFriend(AddDogFriendViewModel model)
{

    model.Dog = new Dog();
    model.Dog = dogFaceDbContext.Dogs.Include("DogFriends").Where(d => d.FirstName == model.DogFriendSearchInput).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(model);
}
```

If lazy loading is enabled you won't need the include (Dogs.Include("DogFriends"))

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review and answer! With your pointing out the circular reference i was able to get a clearer view. I still used my own viewmodels with small adaptions, will post my solution later tonight!